# Cannot login to PostgreSQL when I specify "-h localhost"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I use Ubuntu 14.10 and installed PostgreSQL 9.2 from PostgreSQL official apt repository. (apt.postgresql.org)

When I switched user `postgres` and try following command, I can successfully login.

```
$ psql -U postgres dbname -W
Password for user postgres: (Enter Password)
psql (9.2.9)
Type "help" for help.

dbname=#
```

However, when I specify host value, I cannot login with following error.

```
$ psql -h localhost -U postgres notel -W
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I'm trying to connect from Sequelize.js, an ORM for node.js, but I experienced almost the same error message:

```
Possibly unhandled Error: error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

### Edit

My pg_hba.conf is as follows:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I refered document about pg_hba.conf, but I don't know what's wrong...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely this has to do with the client authentication file: `pg_hba.conf`.
It holds entries for each host/socket/user/password/database combination.

When you change your host to `localhost`, you have a different access route than when you connect directly over a Unix socket. You will patch yourself through TCP/IP instead of going "directly". If you open your `pg_hba.conf` file, you will find a bunch of rules at the end. These rules define which combinations are allowed to access the database.

In your case, look for lines that start with `host`, which means access through TCP/IP (and thus `localhost`) as opposed to `local` which means a Unix socket.

Probably there is a line tucked in there which prevents `host` connection access, or not via the credentials you think are correct (`peer`/`md5` pitfall, read below).

As you show in your `pg_hba.conf` file you have `local` entries with `peer` authentication and `host` entries with `md5` authentication. If you don't know the difference between the two authentication mechanisms, then that is your culprit at the moment and can cause some serious head-banging (not the Metal kind; the Against-a-wall kind).

**Common pitfall**

To avoid possible confusion, the difference between `peer` and `md5` is ground for a common pitfall. They both use a user called `postgres` (when using `-U postgres`, that is), but the former is actual a `Unix` user created during installment of your PostgreSQL system, the latter is a `database` user created inside your PostgreSQL bookkeeping tables.

Always remember, if your setting is `peer`, use the credentials of the `Unix` user, if it is `md5` use the credentials of the `database` user.

If no password has been set for the `database` user `postgres`, make sure you set one first. Empty passwords are not allowed either.

**Extra notes**

Always try to make your rules specific, avoid too many `all` entries for databases and users as this could put your installation wide open.

The first line that fits your access combination will be picked and any subsequent lines will be ignored. Make sure that there is no higher line that overwrites your rule.

Remember to restart your PostgreSQL daemon after changing this file, otherwise the changes won't be picked up.

Comment: Thanks. I confirmed my pg_hba.conf and updated question. I didn't edit pg_hba.conf and I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: Just a wild question, but did you ever set a password for the user `postgres` after installation? I guess not, because `peer` is working (which uses your *OS* `postgres` user/password) and `md5` is using the *database* `postgres` user/password. These two are different users. If you switch the `md5` to `peer` for `host`, most likely you would be able to login with the credentials you know.

Comment: I already set password for postgres role. (Not OS user) I can login without `-h` option.

Comment: Yes, but without the `-h` option, you are logging in via `peer` authentication, *not* via `md5`, as shown in your `pg_hba.conf` file. Again, `peer` and `md5` use *different* users (though the same name) to authenticate. Are you sure you are using the correct credentials (possibly different in both cases)?

Comment: Also, ignore my comment about switching to `peer` for `host` entries, this type of authentication is only supported for `local` types. (I was sleeping apparently...)

Comment: Well, so when I try login with `-h`, `psql` trys to connect via TCP/IP and use config starting with `host`? And without `-h`, `psql trys to connect via Unix domain socket and use config starting with `local`? (Or opposite?)

Comment: I tried to change auth method of `host` to `peer`, but when I restart postgres, it says `peer authentication is only supported on local sockets`.

Comment: First, correct, `-h` uses TCP/IP, thus `host` (`localhost` translates to an IP and port). No direct Unix socket. Second, indeed, read a few comments back, `peer` is only for `local` types, sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66710/discussion-between-timusan-and-phanect).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a secure "localhost" login with *$ psql -U username dbname -h localhost -W*

You need to make sure the user has been setup with an encrypted password and also setup your "pg_hba.conf" correctly to be "samehost".

**1.) Create a Secure Login: "$ psql dbname"**

```
ALTER USER username with encrypted password 'your_password';
```

**2.) Modify "pg_hba.conf" as your main "postgres" user**

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             samehost                md5
```

**3.) Restart your PostgreSQL server**

```
service postgresql restart
```

If you have any other problems read your PostgreSQL log carefully at "/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log/*.log"

Comment: Thx, that helped in my case. I forgot to make sure the password is created using "encrypted password".

Answer (score -1):

sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf

and set listening address: localhost

sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf

IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             localhost                md5